# SSIS Creates 0 KB Pdf files

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, vbscript, ssis

I want to export PDF files using SSIS.  The report to export has one parameter (type = integer).  I found code on the internet that does exactly this [here](http://www.msbiblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/24/run-and-export-ssrs-reports-from-ssis-sql-server-2008/).

However, when I run this code from ssis, it exports the pdf but the file size is 0KB. I get an error when trying to open the pdf file.

Below is the code I am using:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Diagnostics




<System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version:="1.0", Publisher:="", Description:="")> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)>
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase

    Enum ScriptResults
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    End Enum
    Protected Sub SaveFile(ByVal url As String, ByVal localpath As String)
        Dim loRequest As System.Net.HttpWebRequest
        Dim myCredentials As New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
        Dim loResponse As System.Net.HttpWebResponse
        Dim loResponseStream As System.IO.Stream
        Dim loFileStream As New System.IO.FileStream(localpath, System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write)
        Dim laBytes(256) As Byte
        Dim liCount As Integer = 1
        Try

            loRequest = CType(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
            loRequest.Credentials = myCredentials
            loRequest.Timeout = 600000
            loRequest.Method = "GET"
            loResponse = CType(loRequest.GetResponse, System.Net.HttpWebResponse)
            loResponseStream = loResponse.GetResponseStream
            Do While liCount > 0
                liCount = loResponseStream.Read(laBytes, 0, 256)
                loFileStream.Write(laBytes, 0, liCount)
            Loop
            loFileStream.Flush()
            loFileStream.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim url, destination As String

        destination = Dts.Variables("varDestinationPath").Value.ToString + "\" + Dts.Variables("varRSParameter").Value.ToString + " " + Format(Now, "yyyyMMdd") + ".pdf"
        url = "http://Server/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMap%2fMap%2fMap%2Repportname&Parameter=" + Dts.Variables("varRSParameter").Value.ToString + "&rs:Format=PDF"
        SaveFile(url, destination)



        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success

    End Sub
```

I tried to go to the URL http://Server/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMapName%2fMapName%2fMapName%2Repportname&Parameter="parametersqlresults"Format=PDF

When I do this I get a download of the pdf and everything works ok.

I thought that there could be something with connection to the reporting server, so I added this to the code:

```
`Imports System.Net
Dim myCredentials As New NetworkCredential("username", "password")
loRequest.Credentials = myCredentials`
```

Also on the reporting server in the windows logs > security 
I can see Audit success with the provided username and password.

I changed the location to where the pdf is saved to several locations.  I also changed the variables data type from data type 'String' to 'INT32'
with no success

[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAFEx.png)

Comment: For the url that you stated that worked if you went to it manually does not follow the same format of the url that is in the code.  is this a typo?

Comment: I cant see the typo?. but  in my VBscript  when i hold down CTRL it asks for credentials and the parameter after filling those in i can see the report.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem happen a couple of months ago, fixed it, forgot about it, and when we had a server upgrade have it happen again only to bang my head against the wall trying to figure out how to fix it.

The problem is when you are running the code, you are running as yourself and likely have "browser" (or better) permissions on the SSRS website.  When you run this as a SQL job, the job runs through the SQL Agent account or proxy account.  You need to grant that SQL account those browser rights on the SSRS side as well.

Hope that helps,
Ryan Davidson